# MongoDB group-wise pagination

Tags: mongodb

Is there any query with pagination (skip, limit) where I can paginate based on a property or group.

**e.g.** If I have a Category and Product collections, where each product belongs to a category. Now I can easily query for products with pagination (skip, limit).

Is there any way to query for products where I can use pagination (skip, limit) based on the Products category properties. 
e.g. accessing 10 products (maybe limit of 10) for each category.

Comment: Please post a schema (even if simple) in order to give back an example of code.

Comment: to be clear, are you wanting to paginate the products or the categories? (limit 12 to return the first 10 category As and 2 category Bs, or limit 2 to get 10 category As and 10 category Bs)

Comment: product 
{
 _id,
 name,
 ....
 category : (_id Relation with Category)
}

category 
{
 _id,
 name
 ....
}

product.find({category: {$in: [1,2]}}).limit(10);
But I need something where I get 10 products from each category and for page 2 again I need to access next 10 products from each category .. and so oon

Comment: @JayantaBaishya solution posted

Answer (score 1):

In order to paginate products based on the category they depend, MongoDB must query by category (get all category, or maybe get all  subCategory) and then *join* the products for each category. When you *join* the product you can *skip* for rows you already have and *limit* for the number of product per page you have.

Suppose

- you want the pagination only for subCategory **sport**
- *test002_Product* is the collection category

Then:

1. page1 has skip:0 and limit:10
2. page2 has skip:10 and limit:10
3. page3 has skip:20 and limit:10

code:

```
db.getCollection("test002_Category").aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
                "subCategory": "sport" // you can delete it...
          }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "test002_Product",
                let: {
                    categoryID: "$_id"
                }, 
                // join:
                pipeline: [{
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: ["$category", "$$categoryID"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $skip: 0 // skip first rows
                    },
                    {
                        $limit: 2 // limit product for page
                    }
                ],
                as: "products"
            }
        }
    ]);
```

**page1 result:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0e94737098b608de30bb"), 
    "name" : "Cat_A", 
    "subCategory" : "sport", 
    "products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0ef7737098b608de30c3"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e94737098b608de30bb"), 
            "name" : "A1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0efb737098b608de30c4"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e94737098b608de30bb"), 
            "name" : "A2"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0e9c737098b608de30bc"), 
    "name" : "Cat_B", 
    "subCategory" : "sport", 
    "products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0f18737098b608de30d0"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e9c737098b608de30bc"), 
            "name" : "B1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0f18737098b608de30d1"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e9c737098b608de30bc"), 
            "name" : "B2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**page2 result:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0e94737098b608de30bb"), 
    "name" : "Cat_A", 
    "subCategory" : "sport", 
    "products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0eff737098b608de30c8"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e94737098b608de30bb"), 
            "name" : "A3"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0eff737098b608de30c9"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e94737098b608de30bb"), 
            "name" : "A4"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0e9c737098b608de30bc"), 
    "name" : "Cat_B", 
    "subCategory" : "sport", 
    "products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0f18737098b608de30d2"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e9c737098b608de30bc"), 
            "name" : "B3"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7c0f18737098b608de30d3"), 
            "category" : ObjectId("5b7c0e9c737098b608de30bc"), 
            "name" : "B4"
        }
    ]
}
```